# Sending email through gmail SMTP on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Is this possible?  I am able to send through localhost, but on godaddy the email doesn't get sent.  Has anyone managed to achieve this?

I'm using C#

Answer (score 15):

It appears that GoDaddy blocks the SSL ports required by gmail's smtp access.  This means you are out of luck at this point.  You could just use GoDaddy's local relay:

relay-hosting.secureserver.net
with no credentials.

http://help.godaddy.com/article/955

Comment: The link in @Chris answer is also relevant here. http://help.godaddy.com/article/1073

Comment: Thanks, Just follow this link and set configuration like below and it will start working. Thanks, @jkelley.
<appSettings>
<add key="Email_SMTP_client_name" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" />
    <add key="Email_SMTP_port_number" value="25" />
    <add key="Email_UseDefaultCredentials" value="false" />
    <add key="Email_EnableSsl" value="false" />
</appSettings>

Answer (score 12):

I was able to send an email through GoDaddy using these settings in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp>
                <network 
                    host="smtpout.secureserver.net" 
                    userName="emailaccount@yourdomain.com" 
                    password="****" />
                <!--
                As per @Yoro's comment you might have
                luck including the port number as well
                -->
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

and this code:

```
var SmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
SmtpClient.Send("emailaccount@yourdomain.com", "to@whatever.com", "subject", "body");
```

Note I believe that the from address in the email you are sending has to be from your domain. I tried sending an email as coming form another domain and got an error message.

You have to make sure you have an email account in GoDaddy, you can check by logging in and going to Products > Email > Email Plans. You also have to make sure SMTP relay is turned on, it was turned on by default for me. Also important to know by default my GoDaddy account  only allows me to send 250 emails a day.

Comment: I was able to send email to GoDaddy by adding port to the mail settings.

Comment: @CodeBlend port="80"

Comment: that's godaddy outbound smtp smtpout.secureserver.net. I'ved tried all port 80, 25,3535, they all seem to work on my local host, but when I try to run the same application code through their shared webhosting. I get a blocked port error for port 25, and the other 80 and 3535 port i get a no answer back. I talked to godaddy tech support, they said all the ports i'ved used is open. And it works on my localhost, but not on their web hosting? This is really confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I am creating a simple contact form using ASP.Net MVC 3 on GoDaddy. I wanted to be able to send the emails to accounts hosted on Google Apps. This question matched my situation, but only this [GoDaddy help article](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1073) really solved my problem. Hope it helps someone else!

Code sample from the article:

```
    // language -- C#
// import namespace
using System.Web.Mail;

private void SendEmail()
{
   const string SERVER = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
   MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
   oMail.From = "emailaddress@domainname";
   oMail.To = "emailaddress@domainname";
   oMail.Subject = "Test email subject";
   oMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html; // enumeration
   oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High; // enumeration
   oMail.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now;
   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SERVER;
   SmtpMail.Send(oMail);
   oMail = null; // free up resources
}
```

Comment: I realize your reply is a few years old. I am having the exact same problem, and for some reason your code is not working for me with a godaddy email account. I am able to send emails with this same code through Gmail though, which is strange, and after contacting Godaddy support they tell me all the email account settings are correct. Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: I hope you have figured out your issue by now @DigiOzMultimedia, but if not, are you using an gmail.com address or Google apps domain. Perhaps you already saw this in the article, but from addresses of gmail.com are not allowed on GoDaddy's servers

Comment: Love you man, your solution worked for me with minor adjustments like I used system.net.MailMessage() and oMail.isHTMLbody = true;

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a common issue.

There are two things required.

- Add a user that will be used for authentication.  You can't send anonymously via GoDaddy
- Follow the configuration specified here.

This should make it work correctly.

Comment: so it IS possible to send mail programmatically through google apps mails servers from GoDaddy)?

Comment: Yes.   It should work fine, provided you do everything correctly.

Comment: The 'configuration specified here' link you provided is giving me ASP.NET errors... :-s

Comment: @jonathanconway: It was working when I posted it.  Hopefully they'll get their site fixed soon ;)

Comment: really? Still broken for me. "Server Error in '/' Application. "Could not find stored procedure 'Nop_SettingLoadAll'.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'Nop_SettingLoadAll'."

Comment: that link is now dead reed

Comment: I changed the link to something invalid.  It had become link spam.

Answer (score 3):

For people who still looking for an answer try this

```
smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secure.net";
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Port = 25;
```

Comment: relay-hosting.secureserver.net

Answer (score 2):

When using relay-hosting with Godaddy the email objects FROM email address MUST be a Godaddy "white Listed" email.

They do this to stop spammers hijacking an account

There is an alternative for using the relay-host

Using the GoDaddy form-mailer, (Google Serach: "_gdForm/webformmailer.asp")

This alternative can be used to send a pre-designated "form-mailer" email account all the web forms and it does work!  but does require some hosting.content.form-mailer setup on GoDaddy.

check out how I've used the form-mailer:

(only catch is, it takes away the ability to code a subscribe/unsubscribe XML database, as the form data is sent off to this inaccessable ASP file) So I may end up revert back to using relay hosting in ASP.NET

www.earthed.net.au\News.aspx
www.earthed.net.au\Contact.aspx
www.earthed.net.au\Support.aspx

My ultimate goal was to have an email come into my inbox from joe@blogs.com with the necessry form field data, but no matter how you go your Host provider's security setting will ultimately determine your ability to do this.

Also tried using google and hotmail smtp hosts (as I have an account with each) and same secirty restriction story, maybe a lesser known free web email provider that has lower security settings allowing full relay hosting (if so let me know)

Answer (score 2):

The last time I tried doing this (maybe early 2011-ish) I was not able to programmatically send out from Gmail account on GoDaddy. I took code the exact same code that worked on a different hosting company's server and it failed on GoDaddy's server so I'm quite confident that the code was not the issue.

I called their tech support and got conflicting information but I had heard enough to convince myself sending via Gmail was not a for sure supported service on GoDaddy's servers.

I was also given the workaround option of using their web email form which is totally not what the project I was working on could use and underscored the notion that GoDaddy did not fully understand what they talking about.

In the end I found that I was able to just use GoDaddy's SMTP servers and plug in my own "from" address which allowed me to send mail to any email address and to spoof the origination email address. So they end up locking down legitimate email functionality and instead force you to use a highly abusable system instead.

Again, this was a while ago that I ran into this issue but it would be easy enough to check to see if they still allow you to use their SMTP server to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

Almost forgot here are googles detailed instructions. The above tool will change automatically 8-)

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33353

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to find another host. When I was coding for a site on godaddy I remember asking godaddy whether they disabled their mapi functions and it turns out they do a little more than just disable it. I've heard they filter specific outgoing ports.

Answer (score 0):

This Code works

```cs
// Create the msg object to be sent

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
// Add your email address to the recipients
msg.To.Add("mr@soundout.net");
// Configure the address we are sending the mail from
MailAddress address = new MailAddress("mr@soundout.net");
msg.From = address;
msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
msg.Body = txtName.Text + "n" + txtEmail.Text + "n" + txtMessage.Text;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
client.Port = 25;

// Send the msg
client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing the same issue you are describing in your question, I finally figure out a solution.

Check your web.config file and make sure that the debug property is set to false whenever you publish your website. Let me know if this works. It did for me.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>    
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>      
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar, just got reset emails and register emails, had to change the `$header` to `noreply@zzz.com` to match the website address.  Didn't need `SMTP`, just takes forever to receive the email....still a work in progress.

```
            $subject = "Please reset your password";
            $message = " Here is your password reset code {$validation_code}

             Click here to reset your password http://www.zzz.com/Login_App/code.php?email=$email&code=$validation_code
            ";

            $headers = "From: noreply@zzz.com";
```