# how many time per day can I use phpmailer->send()?

Tags: php, linux, email, hosting, phpmailer

This is really a student-like question..

I've been working on a ticket-reserve thing for an exhibition organiser. They are using a basic Godaddy shared hosting plan.

After making a reservation (and payment), the user will receive by email a ticket on which a codebar, the username and so on. I simply used phpmailer's send() because email sending via SMTP is very much limited by GoDaddy.  Well.. our tickets would never be too popular but several days in a year there could be hundreds people buying tickets per day..

Sorry about the long background.

My question is: usually, do providers limit the time of using send(), mail(), sendmail() in php? I know some providers forbid such functions, but obviously some not. Those functions only have something to do with the CPU --- if the cpu feels it acceptable, then as many tickets as possible can be sent, right?

I did asked Godaddy several times (waiting in line 30+ minutes every time), but they didn't know. So please share little bit your experience, thank you very much!

And if there is any problem please favour me with your instructions..

> > I simply used phpmailer's send() because email sending via SMTP is very much limited by GoDaddy.

Please let me make it clearer here.. I did not use SMTP and I don't want to touch the 250 SMTP Relay for each email address -- I could, but that is really a different topic. I simply want to use phpmailer's send() function without any SMTP setting, and I wonder if there is any limitation (e.g. 1000 times to use this function)..
Thank you again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer does not set any limits, nor does the `mail()` function, it's only ISPs like GoDaddy that do. However, they do so by blocking access to normal SMTP ports, and/or redirecting SMTP connections to their own servers (`*.secureserver.*`). It's still possible to connect to mail servers on other non-standard ports, for example port 80, or send via HTTP APIs such as SendGrid provides. This does imply that you have access to a mail server that allows such things, and if you do, you're probably not the kind to host on GoDaddy.

I don't know for sure, but GoDaddy may be able to raise your limit on request - the low default limit is a defensive measure against things like the many hacked wordpress installs they host. You should ask.

Generally they should block or redirect outbound port 25, but blocking access to port 587 is really just being obnoxious as it implies access to a mail server that requires both encryption and authentication.

Comment: "However, they do so by blocking access to normal SMTP ports, and/or redirecting SMTP connections to their own servers (*.secureserver.*)."

I think you have answered my question! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Funny they are usually helpful.

Its called SMTP Relays and it is defined on a per (sending) email basis but usually defaults to 250.

Login to the Workspace email manager, and edit the account you are using to send the emails as, you can alter the number there, although I couldnt tell you what the maximum supported count is.

They set this to prevent spam usually from caused by a virus or runaway script.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, are you a Godaddy user? If you use Workspace email please be careful that they also have a different mail system in Cpenal (there are 2 places that you can find email service). Many people have problem sending email via SMTP, from their Workspace email address -- should use Cpenal email service: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25225972/5416214