# SMTP settings with godaddy

Tags: php, email, encryption, smtp

I need to know the settings for sending STMP emails with encryption tls.
I want to send emails from my godaddy accounts, all my emails accounts are hosting in godaddy.
This is my configuration (I use PHPMAILER):

```
$pMail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
$pMail->Username = "emailgodaddy@godaddy.com";
$pMail->Port = 465
$pMail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$pMail->Password = "mypassword"
$pMail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

If I change the Port to 80 (and deactivated SMTPSECURE) I can send emails, but those emails are not encrypted!. When I use Port=465 show this error: **Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111).**

I know I can send mails with these settings:

```
$pMail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$pMail->Port = 25;
$pMail->SMTPAuth = false;
$pMail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

But those emails are not sent encrypted. I need send mails through SMTP because if the emails sent with the method mail() or sendmail() are not sent for more than a month!. I contacted with godaddy many times and I haven't been given any solutions. And I know it's not a source code problem because for many months the emails have been sent correctly. I also have two different websites in the same hosting and I don't get email from either. I need a solution until I migrate to another server, because I'm very sick of godaddy, I wouldn't recommend it to my worst enemy!

What settings I need to send encrypted emails?. Or what other solution can I apply?

EDIT: After days godaddy told me that there's no problem sending emails from port 25. I don't trust them because I think that they don't know what is the problem and I know that port 25 isn't a secure port. Support don't use the word "secure" but told me that there's no problem...

Comment: Then ask Godaddy! Or look at their help documentation

Comment: I asked godaddy twice and they have not given me a solution, just a: let's check the problem. Translation: We have no idea what happens.

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841834/phpmailer-godaddy-server-smtp-connection-refused

Comment: This seems to agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084652/issue-on-how-to-setup-smtp-using-phpmailer-in-godaddy-server

Comment: Yes, I had already checked those links. The second link doesn't provide a solution, and the first could a be solution but I'm waiting for godaddy to confirm that I can do it! (move my emails accounts). Meanwhile I tried to apply a solution to be able to send encrypted emails. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but, maybe the answer can help somebody else. I just talked to GoDaddy about the issue and the needed configration they told me was like:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtpout.secureserver.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 80
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

these are the django config settings but, I'm sure that it can be copied to other platforms.