# Unable to send mail using PHP using Godaddy email credentials

Tags: php

**code:**

```
<?php
    try {
        require_once "Mail.php";
        require_once "Mail/mime.php";
        $from = "support@domain.com";
        $to = "user@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Testing email please ignore";
        $message = "Just testing";
        $host = "godaddyhost";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "support@domain.com";
        $password = "password";
        $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message); 
        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) { 
              echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
                echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    ?>
```

I'm facing an issue in the browser on executing the above `script`

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

If I comment my code from `$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);` and just simply `echo "something";` then I can see something on my browser

Log

```
[Wed Dec 27 17:07:36.033665 2017] [:error] [pid 28115] [client ::1:41546] PHP Warning:  include_once(Net/SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
[Wed Dec 27 17:07:36.033715 2017] [:error] [pid 28115] [client ::1:41546] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
[Wed Dec 27 17:07:36.033741 2017] [:error] [pid 28115] [client ::1:41546] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /usr/share/php/Mail/smtp.php on line 366
```

Comment: It seems you have not installed SMTP on your server.

Comment: I'm trying from localhost

Comment: It's irrelevant. So you have not installed SMTP on your local server.

Comment: check your error log and paste in question

Comment: You mean we have to install SMTP on godaddy server?

Comment: Added error log @ChetanAmeta

Comment: so SMTP is  not installed. have a look at https://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install "Net/" classes.

Use this command on Linux machine,`sudo pear install Net_SMTP` OR

`pear install Net_SMTP` for windows machine. OR

downloaded the following, and put them in /Net

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/download

http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket/download

Comment: I'm facing this exception now 
Failed to connect to smtpout.asia.secureserver.net:465 [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: -1, response: )]

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841834/phpmailer-godaddy-server-smtp-connection-refused