# Trying to send email from gmail using smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, phpmailer

**I can't send Email from my gmail account by php**
*Here is code. I am trying to send email from gmail using smtp.gmail.com, but it's giving error*

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //gmail SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com';   //username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';   //password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Port = 465;                    //smtp port
$mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com','Artisans Web');
$mail->addAddress('mymail@gmail.com', 'User Name');
//  $mail->addAttachment(__DIR__ . '/attachment1.png');
//  $mail->addAttachment(__DIR__ . '/attachment2.jpg');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Email Subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Email Body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

This is the error:

> 2018-02-13 06:12:41 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Usename probably doesn't need `@gmail.com`.

Comment: yes, thankyou for responce.

Comment: You should set `SMTPOptions` *before* you try to send the mail.

Comment: Please check no i updated the question.

Comment: Did you try reading the web page in the error message? It has a section explaining that error message.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: What web hosting service are you using? If it's GoDaddy, the web page has a section about them as well.

Comment: $mail->Port = 587;  you should try to change your port like 465 to 587.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Gmail uses both ports.

Comment: @barmar, yes i did, ping is connecting good, am using Xamp not have SMTP server. am using my gmail for testing

Comment: Did you try turning on SMTP Debugging?

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd , I tried 25, 465 and 587 and tls,ssl still it not connecting. error `SMTP connect() failed`

Comment: @Barmar- I entered in code `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, itried to enter `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;` its giving error

Comment: As all the above comments suggest, and the troubleshooting guide describes in detail, your ISP is blocking outbound SMTP. This is a problem with your ISP, not your code. You also search before posting - there are many questions like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why php is sending email from localhost not from server using PHPMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786048/why-php-is-sending-email-from-localhost-not-from-server-using-phpmailer)

Comment: To use gmail smtp, you also need to allow access from "less secure apps" (or similar phrasing). You should get an email from gmail telling you that access was blocked, with a link to enable the setting.

Comment: @ Karsten Koop , thank you for replay, i did `less secure apps` as allow access but same error is there

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled less secure app access on your Gmail account? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for response,  yes I Did

Comment: I found answer. that was **PHPmailer** have problem from github. i took from my friend its working. Thank you for support guys