# Laravel not sending emails on GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gmail, laravel-6

The following settings work on localhost but after uploading on godaddy hosting server email is not being send.

> .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=babuliprasadsinghxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I am using laravel beautimail package

> mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

Comment: what about your mail.php file under the config folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP on GoDaddy Linux Shared trying to send through GMAIL SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440026/php-on-godaddy-linux-shared-trying-to-send-through-gmail-smtp)

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem, the work around is to send mail using mailgun's API rather than via its smtp. so your mail.php (in App/config/mail.php) should look like this:

```
...
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),

....
'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
            'domain' => 'YOUR_MAILGUN_DOMAIN',
            'secret' => 'YOU_MAILGUN_API_KEY',
            'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'YOUR_MAILGUN_API_ENDPOINT'),
```

Then edit your .env file to be

```
...
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=null
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_MAILGUN_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_MAILGUN_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@yoursite.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
        ],
```

finally clear your app cache
run `php artisan config:cache`

to manually clear your cache on shared hosting, follow one of the numerous suggestions here
[How to clear laravel cache on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server)

So basically under-the-hood we are just making a cURL POST request to mailgun.