# in Codeigniter Unable to send email - fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl, gmail

etting  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused) while sending email.

My email Controller is  :

```
public function send() { 
     $from = "abc@gmail.com"; 
     $to = $this->input->post('email'); 
     date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

     $ci = get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "abc@gmail.com"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "Mypwd";
        $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";
        $config['mailtype'] = "text";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $ci->email->initialize($config);

     $this->email->from($from, 'Your Name'); 
     $this->email->to($to);
     $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
     $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 

     //Send mail 
     if($this->email->send()) {

     $this->load->view('pages/successfully'); }
     else {

    echo "Error in sending Email.";
      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
     }
  }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/simt/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 568
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/simt/public_html/application/controllers/Email.php
>   Line: 46
>   Function: show_error
>
> File: /home/simt/public_html/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused means exactly that the connection to the peer was refused. This is because the server either does not expect connections at the port or because a firewall is blocking the connection. It is probably the last one in your case so check for firewalls which might block the access on the local machine but also in the network. It might also that a firewall in front of the server or the server itself is blocking access for example if your system is on some blacklist known for sending spam.

Comment: I try it form form other system, same error. so can i talk with server provider ?

Comment: @harvinder: I have no idea where your software is running but yes, if there are others managing the systems and maybe configuring firewalls then talk to them.

Comment: @harvinder: Yes, godaddy might block this port. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1583409/3081018.